# Angular 5 | What is the best way to display xml generic files in a form?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, angular, forms

I'm working on an angular 5 project where I have to display xml schemes as HTML forms.

**I've tried to use some xml to JS object converters** and then recuresively loop through its keys and values to build a form from them. It worked but not in an ideal way.

For example, if I have an array property, lets call it "computer", and for each computer I have an array of properties, I'm only getting for the first computer[0] it's key name (computer). for the other ones I gate number (1 - array length).

```
This is my object. I would like to get instead of 1-5 the key name "computer". 
For now only instead of 0 I get 'computer'

Comm_CoreComputers:
computer: Array(6)
0: {header: Array(1), computerName: Array(1), ipAddress1: Array(1), 
ipAddress2: Array(1), broadcastAddress1: Array(1), …}
1: {header: Array(1), computerName: Array(1), ipAddress1: Array(1), 
ipAddress2: Array(1), broadcastAddress1: Array(1), …}
2: {header: Array(1), computerName: Array(1), ipAddress1: Array(1), 
ipAddress2: Array(1), broadcastAddress1: Array(1), …}
3: {header: Array(1), computerName: Array(1), ipAddress1: Array(1), 
ipAddress2: Array(1), broadcastAddress1: Array(1), …}
4: {header: Array(1), computerName: Array(1), ipAddress1: Array(1), 
ipAddress2: Array(1), broadcastAddress1: Array(1), …}
5: {header: Array(1), computerName: Array(1), ipAddress1: Array(1), 
ipAddress2: Array(1), broadcastAddress1: Array(1), …}
```

To simplify the problem, **how can I get for each property in the array, the array name as a key?**

Any help will be appreciated.